# Package loading in R across multiple cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing, package

I've written a function to streamline package installation, updating and loading:

```
LoadPackages <- function(package.list){
  if (length(intersect(package.list, old.packages()[, "Package"]))) 
    update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
  new.package.list <- setdiff(package.list, installed.packages()[, "Package"])
  if (length(new.package.list)) 
    install.packages(new.package.list, dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com')
  attached <- search()
  unloaded.package.list <- setdiff(package.list, gsub("package:", "", attached[grepl("package", attached)]))
  if (length(unloaded.package.list))
    sapply(unloaded.package.list, require, character.only=TRUE)
}
```

When I use it normally, there's no issue, and it works great. However, I'm just getting into parallel computation in R, and the function I want to use parLapply on depends on several packages, so I attempted to load them by sourcing the R file where LoadPackages lives and calling it:

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  source("S:/Innovation Office/innovation/all/r/inn_all_r.R")
  LoadPackages(c('dplyr', 'ggplot2', 'ifultools', 'scales'))
})
```

and I get this error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  7 nodes produced errors; first error: trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
```

That's a little puzzling to me because I do set the repository in the only function that takes it as an argument. But nevertheless, I tried to add `chooseCRANmirror()` to the top of the function, only to get:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  7 nodes produced errors; first error: cannot choose a CRAN mirror non-interactively
```

I don't know what's going on, or why this error only comes up when I use the function in parallel, but I'd definitely like to have these and my other functions available, so I'd appreciate help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

The `update.packages` function also has a `repos` argument. I think the error will go away if you supply that argument.

The second error occurs because the cluster workers execute non-interactively, so they can't execute interactive functions such as `chooseCRANmirror`.

---

*Update*

`old.packages` also has a `repos` argument. You could set that too, or just use the `options` function to set the default repository. If you add the following lines to the beginning of your `LoadPackages` function, it will set the default repository while the function is executing but reset it when it exits:

```
orig <- options(repos="http://cran.rstudio.com")
on.exit(options(repos=orig))
```

Comment: I added the `repos` argument to `update.packages`, but that didn't fix it.